# How can make a segue that presents the new view like new mail page in iOS mail app?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, presentviewcontroller

I made have first view which user can press a button to add something in a new view controller. I want to present the new view controller on top of the previous one as it is in new mail page in mail app.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

- presentViewController:animated:completion:

You can search in Documentary of Apple to know how to use it.

Comment: thnx for your reply I'll look it up.